# Using Pointers to Return Array from Function in C

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing a piece of code where I have a function that generates random numbers and places them into an array. I'm very lost on how to use pointers and would appreciate any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>  

#define MAX_DATA_SIZE 10
void generate_data(float input_buffer[]); /*prototyping the function*/

int main(void)
{
    float input_buffer[MAX_DATA_SIZE + 2] = { 0 };
    /*calls the array and prints it*/
    return 0;
}

void generate_data(float input_buffer[])
{
    int no_of_data_points;
    int function_ID = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    no_of_data_points = 2 + rand() % (MAX_DATA_SIZE - 2 + 1); /*generates number    of data points that ranges from 2 to MAX DATA SIZE*/
    function_ID = 1 + rand() % (4 - 1 + 1); /*generates function ID that ranges from 1 to 4*/

    input_buffer[0] = no_of_data_points;
    input_buffer[1] = function_ID;

    int i = 2; /*counter for input buffer array*/

    while (i <= no_of_data_points) {
        input_buffer[i] = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        i++;
    }
    return input_buffer;
}
```

Comment: Did you copy the code from somewhere?

Comment: No I wrote it myself, I just don't know how to actually call the function @sourav

Comment: In that case, you need a good book, tutorial or TA. All of them are either unavailable or off-topic at SO.

Comment: `void generate_data(float input_buffer[])` --> `float *generate_data(float input_buffer[])`, call `generate_data(input_buffer);`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below source code. Check comments in code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>  

#define MAX_DATA_SIZE 10
void generate_data(float input_buffer[]); /*prototyping the function*/

int main(void) {
    float input_buffer[MAX_DATA_SIZE + 2] = { 0 };
    int i = 0; /*counter for input buffer array*/

    generate_data(input_buffer); /* Generate Random data*/

    while (i < input_buffer[0]+2) {  /* Print arrey from the begining*/
        printf("input_buffer[%d] = %f\n",i,input_buffer[i]); 
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}

void generate_data(float input_buffer[])
{
    int no_of_data_points;
    int function_ID = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    no_of_data_points = 2 + rand() % (MAX_DATA_SIZE - 2 + 1); /*generates number of data points that ranges from 2 to MAX DATA SIZE*/

    printf("------> %d\n",no_of_data_points); /* Just for understanding*/

    function_ID = 1 + rand() % (4 - 1 + 1);   /*generates function ID that ranges from 1 to 4*/

    input_buffer[0] = no_of_data_points;
    input_buffer[1] = function_ID;

    int i = 2; /*counter for input buffer array*/

    while (i < no_of_data_points+2) { /* Store the "no_of_data_points" to array from i = 2*/ 
        input_buffer[i] = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX;
        i++;
    }

    return; /* Return type is void*/
}
```